# External_sd storage showing in my usb storage

Tags: external-sd, samsung-galaxy-note

My total USB storage on my Galaxy Note is 10.55GB, but I have 14.55GB of `external_sd` storage showing up inside of my USB storage.

I am showing a separate external SDCard with the proper amount of storage.

Just wondering why it would be showing up under my USB storage

Comment: Is windows telling you that you have 14.55GB of storage instead of 10.55GB? Clarify? :)

Comment: Also, could you link a screenshot? Would help to understand the issue :)